# esxi change MKS port

Tags: esxi, port-forwarding

I need to connect to my home esxi box over the web however I cannot use the default port 902 for the console viewer due to firewall restrictions.

Is there a way to change this port somewhere even if i can just do some nat and redirect any other port to that port?

I've had a look around and when I try to connect to the esxi server in vSphere client I cant find anywhere I can specify the port.

I know this is not the recommended way to do this but its a testing server and security is not an absolute must on this box. I also cannot setup a vpn to this box.

Comment: I may have not made it clear enough but I am not looking to change the firewall I need a way to change the port

Comment: "home esxi box"?

Comment: its my own personal box I use as a dev/test server for personal projects, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The vSphere Client uses TCP 443 for the connection to the esxi host.
TCP/UDP 902 is used for the virtual console of the running VM's.

You'll need to have both ports forwarded to your esxi host if you want to have the full functionaltiy of the vSphere Client.

This article shows you how to change the used ports of the vSphere Client:
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1021199

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't appear there is an option to change the remote console port?